# Capitalisation after colon in British English

Tags: british-english, capitalization, colons

From the BBC News website:

> Truss: Ground should have been laid for tax cuts

Shouldn't the first letter after the colon be lowercase? According to [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/capitalization-after-colons/):

> In British English, the first letter after a colon is capitalized only
> if it's a proper noun or an acronym

Comment: The colon is being used here to indicate that Truss (the British PM) said something. The line is not structured as a sentence (the context of the Grammarly rule), but more like a line of a play script.

Comment: @Peter Also, I would say, the line is in the form of a headline. The"rules" of headline formation are very different from those of normal sentence construction, in fact there are very few rules at all in that context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a specific use of a colon which indicates that the following words were quotes from the person. So

> Truss: Ground should have been laid for tax cuts

means

> Truss said "Ground should have been laid for tax cuts".

In quoted sentences the first letter is capitalized, even if the quote is part of a larger sentence. So in this case the capitalization is correct. In other structures the first letter after a colon is not capitalized .